# Программа добавленная в автозапуск не запускается при включении ПК

Tags: c#, автозагрузка

Код добавления таков:

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey myKey Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWAREMicrosoftWindowsCurrentVersionRun", true);
myKey.SetValue("MyProgram", @"C:\Papla\Program.exe");
```

Программа добавляется в автозапуск, но при включении пк она не запускается. Если глянуть в диспетчер задач, т.е. в Автозапуске она есть, и она включена, но всё же не работает. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: от имени какого пользователя она запущена? подозреваю что от system, судя по тому, в какую ветку реестра вы затолкали ее автозапуск

Comment: я запускаю с аккаунта администратора, однако обычным запуском (т.е. не "Запустить от имени администратора")

Comment: Не важно с какого аккаунта вы добавляете приложение в автозагрузку. Посмотрите какой пользователь отображается в диспетчере задач для процесса вашей программы после автозапуска.

Comment: где это можно посмотреть?

Comment: в диспетчере задач

Comment: понятно что в диспетчере задач, но где именно?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89136/discussion-between-rdorn-and-user321409).